# Get injected javascript from a website when testing with Selenium / Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor

I'm using Selenium / Protractor to test my application's UI and html. I have a  that is injected into the sites and I want to grab the contents of this script tag so I can use it for some tests.

An example of the script is below:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">

    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "LocalBusiness",
        "name": "The Best Company Name",
        "image": "https://www.urltowebsite.us/WebContent/Images/Dealer/6/Logo.png?preset=Dealer.Logo",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "19 North Suite 2 ",
            "addressLocality": "Mobile",
            "addressRegion": "MS",
            "postalCode": "39107",
            "addressCountry": "USA"
        },
        "geo": {
            "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
            "latitude": "32.351923",
            "longitude": "-88.73434"
        },
        "openingHoursSpecification": [{
                "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                "dayOfWeek": [
                "Monday"
                ],
                "opens": "07:30:00",
                "closes": "17:00:00"
            },
            {
                "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                "dayOfWeek": [
                "Tuesday"
                ],
                "opens": "07:30:00",
                "closes": "17:00:00"
            },
            {
                "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                "dayOfWeek": [
                "Wednesday"
                ],
                "opens": "07:30:00",
                "closes": "12:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
</script>
```

I tried this method below, which seemed to work some of the time but other times I would just get NULL. Possibly due to timing issues?

```
// site.po.ts (po == page object)
export class Site {
    async getLDJson() {
        const ldJsonScript = await browser.element(by.xpath(
            '//script[@type="application/ld+json"]'
        )).getAttribute('innerHTML');
        const parsedLdJson = JSON.parse(ldJsonScript);
        return parsedLdJson;
    }
}
```

And I would call it before my tests so I could guarantee I had the info

```
// dealership.test.ts
describe('Dealership Site', () => {
    const site: Site = new Site();
    const cu: ContactUsPage = new ContactUsPage();

    beforeAll(async () => {
        await cu.goToDealership();
        browser.sleep(3000);
        await site.getLDJson();
    });
});
```

```
//contact_us.po.ts
    async goToDealership(dealerName: string = 'wilsonsaw', nextPage: string = "") {
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        var url = this.composeUrl(dealerName);

        const currentUrl = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
        url = `${url}${nextPage}`;

        if (url !== currentUrl) {
            await browser.navigate().to(url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`browser.sleep(3000);` needs `await` to wait until it's done

---

```
*  waitUntilElementHasAttribute
*  @param    {ElementFinder}    $element                    Locator of element
*  @param    {String}           attributeName               Attribute of an element to evaluate
*  @param    {number}           [timeout=timeouts.ms1000]   Time in ms (med. is 1000ms)
*  @return   {Promise}
*/
let waitUntilAttributeIsntNull = ($element, attributeName, timeout = 1000) => {
    return browser.wait(
        () => $element.getAttribute(attributeName).then(attributeValue => {
            return attributeValue !== null
        }),
        timeout,
        'Wait until element \'' + $element.locator() + '\' is not null',
    );
}

// usage
await waitUntilAttributeIsntNull(
  element(by.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]')), 
  'innerHTML', 
  3000
)
```

The only thing that may still go wrong, is the function will fail if element is not yet present. I'd recommend to just add regular `wait for presence` and then use this function

Comment: I added the `await` to the `browser.sleep` line but it did not fix the problem I am experiencing. I still get `NULL` as my `ldJsonScript` variable.

Comment: what's your goToDealership function?

Comment: Updated question to include `goToDealership()`

Comment: hm... I'm seeing `browser.navigate().to(url);` for the first time. It's not documented on protractor page. Safer to use browser.get

Comment: okay... so why don't you write a function that will wait until the script is not `null`? sleep 3000 doesn't guaranty anything. Let me know if you need help with that

Comment: Yea! i'd love help with that -- I guess I would use a Promise?

Comment: Would doing something like this help? I'm trying a few things, but still get `NULL`         
--- 
var ld = element(by.xpath(
            '//script[@type="application/ld+json"]'
        )).getAttribute('innerHTML');

        protractor.promise.all([ld]).then(function(r) {
            console.log(r);
        })

Comment: no, thats overcomplecated. I update the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236491/discussion-between-maylortaylor-and-sergey-pleshakov).